# Determine whether vector system $x^2, x^3, |x^3|$ is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

How to determine whether vector system $x^2, x^3, |x^3|$ is linearly independent in vector space $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ or not?

I know that linear independence means that $\lambda_1x^2+\lambda_2x^3+\lambda_3|x^3|=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda_3=0$.

From that I get $x^2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2x)+\lambda_3|x^3|=0$ and
\begin{cases}{
  x^2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2x) = 0, \\
  \lambda_3|x^3|=0
  }
\end{cases}
But how to finish this using definition?

Comment: Your conclusion from $x^2(\lambda_1+\lambda_2x)+\lambda_3|x^3|=0$ is not correct, because it is not a sum of two positive quantities. However, note that $|x^3| = x^2|x|$, which you can follow similarly.

Comment: Substitute $x=1,-1,2$ to get three equations in $\lambda_i$.

Answer (score 1):

I would proceed like that. Dividing by $x^2$ for $x \neq 0$ you get
$$\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 x + \lambda_3 \vert x \vert =0$$

Taking the limit at $0$ implies $\lambda_1 =0 $. Dividing again by $x$ you get the equality $\lambda_2 + \lambda_3 = 0$ valid for all $x \gt 0$. And therefore $\lambda(x - \vert x \vert)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$ where $\lambda=\lambda_2=-\lambda_3$.

Taking finally $x=-1$ you get $\lambda=0$ and can finally conclude.

Comment: Why take the limit? Just set $x=0$.

Comment: @lhf Good remark !!!